# How do I show my switch function that my string variable equals user input

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cin

I have a program with a string variable that equals whatever the user puts in. I am trying to use a switch statement to display a certain message based on the letter the user typed, but don't know how to show the switch program it is an input. I am grateful for any help, part of the code is below.

```
cin >> ans1;
switch(ans1 == "") {
    {case "A" : cout << ": Sorry, the right answer was C.";
    break;}
    {case "B" : cout << ": Sorry, the right answer was C.";
    break;}
    {case "C" : cout << ": Correct! Wow, your pretty smart!";
    break;}
    {case "D" : cout << ": Sorry, the correct answer was C.";
    break;}
```

Comment: `switch(ans1 == "")` ?? That can only have values true or false, not "A", "B" etc...

Comment: See here for all the answers to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Also, you can't use a `string` with a `switch` statement. But you can use a `char`. Why not just use `if/else`? `if (ans1 == "C") {cout << "Correct;} else {cout << "Wrong";}`

Comment: how would I say that ans1 would equal user input, and if the input was a, b, c, d

Comment: oh ok thank you that makes more sense @JohnnyMopp

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sorry to bother you but I started using that program and when i ran it the output would be cout << "right"; whether I got it wrong or right. i put some of the code with the if else statements below

Comment: ` cout << "\n" << first << "\n \n \n \n" << "Messages carried in the nerves in your brain travel how fast?" 
 << "\n \n A- 1,000 mph \n \n B- 200 mph \n \n C- 400 mph \n \n D- 100 mph";
 cout << "\n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n \n"; cin >> ans2;
 if(ans2 == 'B', 'B ', 'b', 'b ') {
  cout << "Wow! Right again!";
 }
 else {
  cout << "Aww, bummer. The right answer was B.";
 }
 `

Comment: What do you mean "show the switch program it is an input?" Also, @John3136 is absolutely correct here. What do you want that line to do (i.e. what did you *think* that that would do)? One final thing: have you stepped through this with a debugger? (Please see [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for advice on that).

Comment: `if(ans2 == 'B', 'B ', 'b', 'b ')` That is not how you compare multiple values. Instead do this: `if (ans2 == 'B' || ans2 == 'b')`. Or you could just convert to upper case: `if (std::toupper(ans2) == 'B')`. Also, I am assuming `ans2` is a `char` and not a `std::string`.

Comment: I never seen such a switch before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `switch statement` with a variable that equals user input, you could use an `if/else statement` (i.e. ans1 == 'C').

```
if (ans1 == 'C') {
    cout << "Correct";
} else {
    cout << "Wrong";
}
```

Thank you `JohnnyMopp5`.